# Нажатием на один инпут выделялись все

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Задача такая, что при нажатии на один чекбокс, нужно чтобы выделялись все. Я понимаю как реализовать это когда они идут один за другим, но мне нужно чтобы не было зависимостей. Если вы посмотрите код, то сами все увидите.

```js
var main = document.querySelector('#shest tr th legend [type="checkbox"]'),
    all = document.querySelectorAll('#shest tr th > [type="checkbox"]');

for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {  // 1 и 2 пункт задачи
    all[i].onclick = function() {
        var allChecked = document.querySelectorAll('#shest tr th > [type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        main.checked = allChecked == all.length;
        main.indeterminate = allChecked > 0 && allChecked < all.length;
    }
}

main.onclick = function() {  // 3
    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
        all[i].checked = this.checked;
    }
}
```

```html
                            <div class="buyer__form">
                                <table border="1">
                                      <fieldset id="shest">
                                       <tr align="left">
                                          <th>
                                              <legend>
                                                  <input type="checkbox" id="all__order">
                                                  <label class="order__label" for="all__order"></label>
                                              </legend>
                                          </th>
                                          <th>Заказ</th>
                                          <th>Дата заказа</th>
                                          <th>К оплате</th>
                                          <th>Статус заказа</th>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr align="left">
                                          <td>
                                              <input type="checkbox" id="order__2">
                                              <label class="order__label" for="order__2"></label>
                                          </td>
                                          <td>350 руб.</td>
                                          <td>от 7 дней</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       </fieldset>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Это попытка реализации, но хотелось бы чтобы зависимостей не было. Пожалуйста подскажите как можно реализовать подобное.

Comment: не работает код.

Comment: Код не работает потому что в js указаны зависимости, а как их убрать я не знаю.. Если можете предложите свой пожалуйста или измените уже существующий)

Comment: я могу это сделать на jQuery.

Comment: Если вас не затруднить. Я был бы благодарен

Comment: Кстати интересная проблема, я бы глянул где прописано, что такой селектор нельзя использовать: без #shest чекбокс находит, с ним нет, с одним id тоже все ок .....

Comment: дело в том, что браузер тупо не рисует fieldset ) в table, а считает невалидной вёрстку и выносит её за пределы table

Comment: а, да, fieldset заменил на tbody все ок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убрал все привязки, правда в том числе и к вёрстке на всякий случай, но думаю, что вы умеете пользоваться селекторами и скорректируете под свои нужды

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
var main = document.querySelector('th input[type="checkbox"]'),
    all = document.querySelectorAll('td input[type="checkbox"]');

for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {  // 1 и 2 пункт задачи
    all[i].onclick = function() {
        var allChecked = document.querySelectorAll('td  [type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        main.checked = allChecked == all.length;
        main.indeterminate = allChecked > 0 && allChecked < all.length;
    }
}


main.addEventListener("click", function() {  // 3
    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
        all[i].checked = this.checked;
    }
});
});
```